# Is there an alternative for --rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls option in Angular CLI 8?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I had a lot of issues because my application is hosted inside a subfolder and for that reason the relative `/assets/` path, which is referenced inside `.scss` files, doesn't work. 
The solution was to enable the `--rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls` option to get the expected behaviour. With that option, the build process has adjusted my `/assets/` paths by injecting the "--base-href" value and now the referenced images and fonts are loading correctly.

However, I see in the documentation that the option is deprecated and it will be removed in the next major release.

https://angular.io/cli/build (search for `--rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls`)

So my question is, what is the alternative, is there any other way to get the same result?

Comment: I think it'll be done automatically in future releases? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14587#issuecomment-497368020

Answer (score 1):

According to the release notes, the recommended method for transition is using relative URLs in your .scss  files. This, to me, seems like a bad idea though. Here’s a comment from the dev team on a bug logged about this issue.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14587#issuecomment-497368020

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by use path in this way:

```
background-image: url('../../../assets/images/icon.png');
```

Instead of this way:

```
background-image: url('/src/assets/images/img.png');
```

Answer (score -2):

If your project is deployed in a subfolder you can pass that information to your `build` command

I suggest you to take a look at [--base-href](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

> In development, you typically start the server in the folder that
>   holds index.html. That's the root folder and you'd add 
>   near the top of index.html because / is the root of the app.
>
> But on the shared or production server, you might serve the app from a
>   subfolder. For example, when the URL to load the app is something like
>   mysite.com/my/app/, the subfolder is my/app/ and you should
>   add  to the server version of the index.html.

You can modify the production base href with the following command:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /subfolder/
```

You can also set base-href to `./` which means the current directory in opposite to `/` which stands for root directory.

Another possible solution would be to change `href` in your main `index.html`

```
<base href="./">
```